# What expression method to use to get back parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Simple question.  I am trying to create a basic lambda expression that returns the parameter.

```
(i, o) => o
```

I have the first part:

```
ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(relationshipItems.ElementType, "i");
ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(instanceEntities.ElementType, "o");
```

And the last part:

```
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(p2return, p1, p2);
```

What method do I use to get back the parameter, presumably as a UnaryExpression(p2return)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the body to be the second parameter, `p2`.  You already have the reference.

```
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(relationshipItems.ElementType, "i");
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(instanceEntities.ElementType, "o");
var body = p2;
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, p1, p2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess you added that extra body = p2 assignment for clarity since its not really needed.  Actually had this solution before, but I screwed up the order in the .Lambda method and went blindly off into another direction.  Thanks for reaffirming it.

Answer (score 0):

If, for the sake of example, we assume p1 is an int and p2 is a string then this:

```
var p1=Expression.Parameter(typeof(int),"i");
var p2=Expression.Parameter(typeof(string),"o");

var lambda=Expression.Lambda(p2,p1,p2);
var function=lambda.Compile() as Func<int,string,string>;
var result=function(10,"hello");
```

will generate a function that returns "o". The lambda will return the value in the last expression in its body, which in the above example is just the parameter p2.